# .sendEmailVerification does not send a verification on the email

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to verify the user by sending an email confirmation from firebase, but I didn't get any, here's the code

```
onCreate(form: NgForm) {
  var user = new User();
  user.name = form.value.name;
  user.email = form.value.email;
  user.contact = form.value.contact;

  if(form.value.gender == "male") {
    user.gender = "male";
  } else {
    user.gender = "female"
  }
  let loading = this.mProv.getLoader('Creating your account...', 0);
  loading.present();
  this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(form.value.email, form.value.password)
    .then(data => {
      let firebaseUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification();

      user.id = data.uid;
      this.userProvider.addUser(user)
        .then(_ =>
          loading.dismiss()
        )
        .catch(error => {
          loading.dismiss();
          this.mProv.showAlertOkMessage('Error','Sign up error. Please try again later.');
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      loading.dismiss();
      this.mProv.showAlertOkMessage('Error','Sign up error. Please try again later.');
    });
}
```

The email is registered on the firebase authentication, but it does not add to the firestore user's section, it shows blank but with an id

[image]

It's supposed to add like this

[image]